How do I reinstall Windows' boot loader if I deleted the EFI partition?
I made a mistake and accidentally deleted my EFI partition for Windows when messing around on Linux. Because I did this BitLocker automatically locked. So grub doesn't recognize and won't boot windows. How do I reinstall the windows bootloader (preferably while preserving grub, although at this point I don't really care, I'll reinstall grub if I need to). I would like to not have to resort to reinstalling windows (because that has its own errors and is loose all my data), but I will if necessary. Also I'm using UEFI mode.

In Windows 2000 thru Windows 10 you could boot from the install disk and choose to perform a repair operation that could fix many boot issues, including restoring the windows bootloader. The exact effect this would have would depend on whether the system was set up for UEFI boot or MBR boot. Also I'm not 100% sure Windows 11 still has this option... though I would expect it to.

For additional clarity it might help to include whether your system is setup to use UEFI boot or MBR boot (it is almost certainly UEFI unless you took steps to change it). Also Windows 11 doesn't really use a boot partition the way *nix can. Windows 11's bootloader is very small and is usually contained in a .efi file on the EFI partition... along side the initial part of the grub boot loader (in a different .efi file). So some clarity on what you mean by "delete my boot partition" might be helpful. Do you mean you deleted the *nix /boot partition?

Sorry for calling it "boot partition"  I didn't know the windows name and that it was supposed to be called the efi partition

no worries, just trying to get more clarity to help myself and others know how to help you. :-)

Boot from the Windows installer. Press Shift-F10 to open the console. Use manage-bde to unlock your system volume (using your BitLocker recovery key), then bcdboot to install the boot loader.
